# How to display a group of videos in a single frame

Tags: python, video

I'm kind of new to python, so please bear with me. I am having trouble displaying videos inside a TKinter frame. What i want to do is play a group of videos inside a frame in TK.

For example: i have 3 videos named a.mp4, b.mp4, and c.mp4 
i want them to play inside a frame without it reloading(closing, then play the next video)

i have tried OpenCV, but what it does is play a.mp4, closes, then plays b.mp4
Any help would be much appreciated, i have been stuck here for days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate videos horizontally or vertically or in a grid to a single video file using ffmpeg or manually in python.

You can use ffmpeg outside python to concatenate videos into single video and show as a single video:
[Vertically stack several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-stack-several-videos-using-ffmpeg/33764934#33764934)

Or you can make a single video by concatenating those videos horizontally or vertically in python itself. e.g. use scikit-video or opencv to load videos into different arrays and concatenate horizontally or vertically or in grid and save as a single video.