# Split 2 video FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, split

can you help me split 2 videos 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rFrJ.png)

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
```

Don't work

My complete log

```
    C:\Users\forumrulez\Desktop\POST>ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-91447-g0bd48ab2d9 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.1 (GCC) 20180709
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 21.104 / 58. 21.104
  libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
  Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 586 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 260x480 [SAR 128:39 DAR 16:9], 428 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
  Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 703 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 360x480 [SAR 64:27 DAR 16:9], 545 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> vstack:input0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> amerge:in0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> vstack:input1
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> amerge:in1
  vstack -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  amerge -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000165b1e6af00] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000165b1e6af00] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[Parsed_vstack_0 @ 00000165b29f1040] Input 1 width 360 does not match input 0 width 260.
[Parsed_vstack_0 @ 00000165b29f1040] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: `[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000165b1e6af00] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_1 @ 00000165b1e6af00] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[Parsed_vstack_0 @ 00000165b29f1040] Input 1 width 360 does not match input 0 width 260.
[Parsed_vstack_0 @ 00000165b29f1040] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: Inputs need the same width to use vstack. Use the scale, scale2ref, crop, and/or pad filters to make each video the same width. Should be lots of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/1109017) (see example #6) on this site.