# How to get image from video and combine other image using ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I want to get a frame from video to combine with other image

using two ffmpeg commands  as:

command 1:

```
  ffmpeg -ss 3 -i video.mp4 -vf \"select=gt(scene\,0.4)\" 
 -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/100 
 -vf scale=150:150  output.jpeg
```

command 2:

```
  ffmpeg -i output.jpeg -i other.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] 
  overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,0,20)'" 
 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output2.jpg
```

how to combine two commands in one, or
how to get frame from video and combine other image in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two commands using the and `&&` after the first command which allows you to execute the second command based on whether the first command completed **successfully**:

```
 ffmpeg -ss 3 -i video.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,4)" 
 -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/100 
 -vf scale=150:150  output.jpeg 

&& 

ffmpeg -i output.jpeg -i other.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] 
  overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,0,20)'" 
 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output2.jpg
```

Now if you want to combine multiple images onto one, Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-or-horizontally-stack-several-videos-using-ffmpeg/33764934#33764934)

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to pass output.jpg to second command. This create two output.jpg just only one

Comment: @MetinBulak I think you have a typo in the first command: `\"select=gt(scene\,0.4)\"` **should be**  `"select=eq(n\,4)"`.

Comment: @MetinBulak Well, it didn't for me, so I concluded it didn't for you either.  Now, were you able to execute both commands in a single one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190005/discussion-between-sendjasni-and-metin-bulak).