# Combine multiple images to form a strip of images ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I wish to combine multiple images into a single strip of images, using FFMPEG.

I have been trying to search this thing on google, but unable to find anything useful. All links take me to places where multiple images are combined to give a video output.

Assuming that all the files are of the same width and height, how can I join them to get a single strip of images. Can anybody help me?

**example image**

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: [Vertically or horizontally stack several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-or-horizontally-stack-several-videos-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: The filter is exactly the same. Just use images as input instead of a video. Have you tried it?