# How to combine two ffmpeg bin script into one script

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="ffmpeg -re -i http://10.10.10.3:9981/stream/channelnumber/9 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://224.2.2.119:2001?pkt_size=188&localaddr=192.168.2.119"
until $cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null; do
echo "restarting ffmpeg command..."
sleep 2

cmd="ffmpeg -re -i http://10.10.10.3:9981/stream/channelnumber/15 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://224.2.2.120:2002?pkt_size=188&localaddr=192.168.2.119"
until $cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null; do
echo "restarting ffmpeg command..."
sleep 2
done
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash

awk '{cmd="ffmpeg -re -i http://10.10.10.3:9981/stream/channelnumber/9 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://224.2.2.119:2001?pkt_size=188&localaddr=192.168.2.119"
until $cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null; do
echo "restarting ffmpeg command..."
sleep 2
}
&
awk '{cmd="ffmpeg -re -i http://10.10.10.3:9981/stream/channelnumber/15 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://224.2.2.120:2002?pkt_size=188&localaddr=192.168.2.119"
until $cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null; do
echo "restarting ffmpeg command..."
sleep 2
}



done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i http://10.10.10.3:9981/stream/channelnumber/9 -i http://10.10.10.3:9981/stream/channelnumber/15 -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts "udp://224.2.2.119:2001?pkt_size=188&localaddr=192.168.2.119" -map 1 -c copy -f mpegts "udp://224.2.2.120:2002?pkt_size=188&localaddr=192.168.2.119"
```

Do not use [`-re`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) for live input streams.

Comment: its possible, these stream combine in one udp stream?

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem Yes. See [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/)