# FFMPEG xstack not recognizing inputs

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-editing

I'm trying to arrange three input videos into a single output video using ffmpeg's xstack. I currently have the operations working with a vstack followed by an hstack, but would like to combine them into an xstack for performance.

I've tried copying the syntax from multiple locations such as:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos%20using%20xstack

[Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-or-horizontally-stack-mosaic-several-videos-using-ffmpeg)

My command is as follows:

> C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i states_full.mp4 -i title.mp4 -i graphs.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a0]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a1]; [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a2]; [a0][a1][a2]xstack=inputs=3:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0_h0[out] " -map "[out]" -c:v libx264 -t '30' -f matroska output.mp4

The command always errors out at the same spot, with the same error message:

> 'w0_0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Some odd behavior is that even when I change the layout section to:

```
layout=w0_0|0_0|w0_h0
```

The error message is still on the middle '0_0' meaning it may be an error in formatting.

This issue is very strange, as the vstack and hstack still work, only the xstack fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, `|` is a special character for the command interpreter, which is the default shell. Quote the layout arg: `layout='0_0|w0_0|w0_h0'`

Comment: Thank you so much, there were a couple other things wrong with my command, but your answer had made debugging significantly easier.