# How to merge several videos in a grid, in one video?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I have 36 video files with same dimensions and want to concatenate them into a one single video with 6x6 grid.

Ideally is non-square number of videos are given for example 12, a 4x3 grid as the most square it can be would be great.

I tried with matplotlib's animation library but failed to concatenate videos in both directions first as row then as columns.

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: I found this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) in less than 10 seconds and it answers your question...

Comment: I found it too but unfortunately if i have 256 videos to merge this method quickly becomes really hard to achieve :/ I am open for any other solutions

Comment: Have you tried `imutils`? It has a `build_montages` [function](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/convenience.py) that may suit your needs.

Comment: See [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP talks about a scaling problem with 256 videos. For that matter I'd recommend automation, for example with Python.
You should generate a command such as the one used at this [link](https://mrod.space/2019/10/04/brady-bunch-video-grid-with-ffmpeg.html) but with your videos and the right amount.
We can see that this part is the one that'll change with the number of videos :

Say you have a list of all videos in python (you could do that by hand but i'd recommand using `os.listdir` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory))

In the same way you'll have to generate the input for the `overlay` filters, this will depend on you output resolution. Let's say it's defined by `width` and `height` variables. Also, in my example the number of videos of the grid (`grid_width` and `grid_width`) are set by hand.
Here is a sample of code I don't have the resource or time to test but this should be a good basis for your work :

```
###list_videos contains the path the the videos
width = 1920
height = 1080
input_videos = ""
input_setpts = "nullsrc=size={}x{} [base];".format(width, height)
input_overlays = "[base][video0] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp0];"
grid_width = 16
grid_height = 16
for index, path_video in enumerate(list_video):
        input_videos += " -i " + path_video
        input_setpts += "[{}:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale={}x{} [video{}];".format(index, width//grid_width, height//grid_height, index)
        if index > 0 and index < len(list_video) - 1:
            input_overlays += "[tmp{}][video{}] overlay=shortest=1:x={}:y={} [tmp{}];".format(index-1, index, width//grid_width * (index%grid_width), height//grid_height * (index//grid_width), index)
        if index == len(list_video) - 1:
            input_overlays += "[tmp{}][video{}] overlay=shortest=1:x={}:y={}".format(index-1, index, width//grid_width * (index%grid_width), height//grid_height * (index//grid_width))

complete_command = "ffmpeg" + input_videos + " -filter_complex \"" + input_setpts + input_overlays + "\" -c:v libx264 output.mp4"

print(complete_command)
```

In the end you can run `complete_command` with [os.system](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/), information [there](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/).

Comment: I am not sure why I got downvoted I searched really hard and had no solutions then created my own post, have a nice day that works great!

Comment: I actually intended to update that blog with something like this but never got around to it. Very cool.

Comment: Thanks for your basis, after fixing some issues I got it to work! I put my changes in an edit

Comment: A more efficient method is to use the hstack, vstack, or xstack filters. See [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/)