# FFMPEG program to crop images and merge them side by side

Tags: ffmpeg, image-editing

So I am trying to make a ffmpeg program for my youtube thumbnails. For now, I have done the part of getting 3 different shorts for my thumbnail. So I want a FFMPEG program to crop all three images into 1280x240px and then end up joining all three images side by side into a 1280x720px image. Please help me out.
[This is how the image layout is, if the above description isnt clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkmWD.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-or-horizontally-stack-mosaic-several-videos-using-ffmpeg#33764934

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-or-horizontally-stack-mosaic-several-videos-using-ffmpeg)