# How to avoid ffmpeg filter_complex overriding the fps of a file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, command, mp4, frame-rate

I'm fairly new to ffmpeg so apologies if this is a simple problem.

I'm trying to tile four 60 fps videos using the script below. It works, but the output is at 25 fps. When I try to use `-r` to force it back to 60, it looks like 25 fps upsampled to 60, counting duplicated frames when rendering.

How can I preserve the original files?

```
ffmpeg -i vln1.mp4 -i vln2.mp4 -i vla.mp4 -i cello.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "nullsrc=size=2800x2400 [base]; \
   [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [A]; \
   [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [B]; \
   [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [C]; \
   [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [D]; \
   [base] [A] overlay=shortest=0 [tmp1]; \
   [tmp1][B] overlay=shortest=0:y=600 [tmp2]; \
   [tmp2][C] overlay=shortest=0:y=1200 [tmp3]; \
   [tmp3][D] overlay=shortest=0:y=1800" \
  -c:v libx264 quartetscore.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the frame rate for the [nullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc) filter (default is 25 fps):

```
ffmpeg -i vln1.mp4 -i vln2.mp4 -i vla.mp4 -i cello.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "nullsrc=size=2800x2400:rate=60 [base]; \
   [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [A]; \
   [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [B]; \
   [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [C]; \
   [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [D]; \
   [base] [A] overlay=shortest=0 [tmp1]; \
   [tmp1][B] overlay=shortest=0:y=600 [tmp2]; \
   [tmp2][C] overlay=shortest=0:y=1200 [tmp3]; \
   [tmp3][D] overlay=shortest=0:y=1800" \ 
  -c:v libx264 quartetscore.mp4
```

Or if you want to stack just use the [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) filter instead of nullsrc and multiple overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i vln1.mp4 -i vln2.mp4 -i vla.mp4 -i cello.mp4 -filter_complex \ 
  "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [A]; \
   [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [B]; \
   [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [C]; \
   [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2800x600 [D]; \
   [A][B][C][D]hstack=inputs=4" \
  -c:v libx264 quartetscore.mp4
```

See [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/) for many more examples.