# Imprint an Image above a video's canvas

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add an image strip above/below a video using ffmpeg, but currently it overlaps the video content.

The command I was using

```
ffmpeg -i ./image_path.png -filter_complex \"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(3000/200)*ih/8/sar:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=0:0\" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4

[wm]overlay=0:-200 Does not imprint anything

"pad=height=ih+40:color=#71cbf4,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h" places at the bottom of the video canvas
```

I want to place my image strip either above or below the video canvas.

Comment: Use the vstack filter as shown in [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/)

Comment: this is awesome worked like a charm. thanks I was browbeating around such complex arguments that I only half understood :) @llogan