# How to splitscreen out of 10 videos? (3840x2160)

Tags: ffmpeg, split

I want splitscreen 10 videos into one with ffmpeg, each video should be in 768x1080 resolution after scaling as I calculated right (3840/5=768, 2160/2=1080)

It's should be looks like this:

[image]

With a video in each case, and all case represent ONE video.

I tried to make something like explain [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) but I'm confused about how I can do it.

How can i do ?

Comment: What did you tried ? Can you more explain your issue ?

Comment: I want splitscreen 10 videos into one with ffmpeg, each video should be in 768x432 resolution after scaling as I calculated right (3840/5=768, 2160/5=432)

Comment: Well, I tried actually to make smth like in ffmpeg docs says, but it confused me too much: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos

Comment: UPD: My maths is wrong, it's should be 768x1080 actually, not 768x432, since there is two rows

Comment: Ok, I just suggest an edit to your question, hope this will be usefull and make someone who knows ffmpeg help you

Comment: Thanks so much for suggest, I appreciate it!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/ for a start. The term is stacking.